# UIView animation returns to origin

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UILabel inside of a UITableViewCell. I am trying to animate the label moving to the right when the user taps the cell. I have this code:

```
CGRect otherFrame = cellLabel.frame;
otherFrame.origin.x +=50;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
    cellLabel.frame = otherFrame;   
}];
```

The odd thing that's happening is that the label is jumping 50 pixels to the left and animating back to its origin (where it was before the action began).

I actually had this working earlier in the week and didn't have any trouble with it, and after scouring through the revision history, I can't figure out where I've gone wrong. I must be missing something stupid.

**EDIT:**
Based on the answer from Jakub, I found that this works:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.01f animations:^{}
completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
     CGRect otherFrame = cellLabel.frame;
     otherFrame.origin.x += 50;
     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
            cellLabel.frame = otherFrame;
    }];

}];
```

Oddly, if I move all of the logic into a completion handler that performs a new animation after the first one completes (without the first actually doing anything), everything animates properly. This is super hacky, and I'm not at all happy with it.

Can anyone think of what would cause the initial animation to move the frame to the negative offset of the intended destination, only to animate it back to its origin, and why triggering a new animation as the completion handler of an empty animation would work?

**EDIT 2:**

I am going to mark Duncan's answer as the right one because it pointed me in the right direction, but I am still baffled why/how these symptoms can happen:

1. The animation moves the frame to the negative offset of the
   destination, then animates it back to the origin (rather than from
   the origin to the destination)
2. Running an empty animation block but adding another animation to the first block's completion handler animates correctly

*Info for the attempted answers:*

3. I have to use auto layout for the project, and as far as I know, I
   can't disable it for a single view
4. I am not putting anything onto a background thread. I didn't try specifically dispatching to the main thread, but I think I was already there. Isn't all visible UI always on the main thread? It was animating, just not as expected.
5. The reason I didn't go the route of changing constraints to begin with is that I am using prototype cells and IB doesn't let you create IBOutlets from prototype cells. There's a bit of work to walk a constraint list and detect a specific one, so I left the constraints blank and tried to animate the frame (and as I said, it was working earlier in the week -- and still worked when animating from an animation block's completion handler).

So the final solution was to add constraints to the container cell (the important one here being the leading), then to animate, I had to find the constraint:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *titleLeadingConstraint = nil;
for( NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in cellLabel.superview.constraints )
{
    if( constraint.firstItem == cellLabel && constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeLeading )
    {
        titleLeadingConstraint = constraint;
    }
}
```

Then set the constraint constant:

```
titleLeadingConstraint.constant = 55.0;
```

Then set the animation block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

This solution should be more future proof (and robust, reliable and stable) than moving the frame, but it turned out to be a fair amount of work in discovery.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please provide a reason so I can at least discern how I failed to meet your standards.

Comment: Its not a cell reuse issue is it?

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get it working. No, you can't turn off auto-layout on a single view, or even on a single scene. It's on or off for an entire file. (Storyboard or XIB) Because XIBs usually only contain a single view controller it is pretty straightforward to turn it off for a single XIB based view controller in a project that otherwise uses Storyboards (yes, you can mix and match the two.)

Comment: As for getting the constraint, the cleaner way to do this is to attach an outlet to the constraint. Then you don't have to search for it.

Comment: When you use auto-layout, the constraints are what determine the geometry of your views, not the views' frames. You have to adjust your thinking. Animating frames/centers doesn't work property in auto-layout. Animate the constraint(s) instead.

Comment: I can't attach an outlet to the constraint in this case (I do that very thing elsewhere in this project) because the view is in a prototype cell. It results in an "Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content" error. I know that the option that would allow that would be to set the table view content to "Static Cells," but that introduces several other challenges to what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have auto layout set in your storyboard or XIB by mistake? (It is on by default). If so you either need to turn AutoLayout off or animate a constraint rather than manipulating your view's frame.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct because it pointed me in the right direction. Take a look at my "EDIT 2"

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the origin after animation.

Comment: I did `[cellLabel setFrame:newFrame];` in the completion handler, and that got me the final result I was looking for, but what happens prior to that isn't good. The animation initially pushes the frame to the left 50 pixels, then animates it back to its original starting position. With this in the completion handler, it then jumps to to proper place on completion. Any ideas?

Comment: Here's a fun one. If I add a completion handler to the animate method, and move the two lines of setup code into that handler, and inside of the handler add another animation that sets the frame of `cellLabel` it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling this code?

Try calling `UIView` `animateWithDuration:...` method on the main thread, in a

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Your animation here
});
```

If this method is not executed on the main thread, it usually jumps to the final stage of the animation.